# How to add GoogleMaps to base layer in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, layers, google-maps

I have a OpenStreetMap for base layer in my website. How can I adding GoogleMaps to base layer, I already have the license API Key.

My base layer OSM:

```
        var map = new ol.Map({
            view: mapView,
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                     source: new ol.source.OSM({
                         attributions: [
                             ' © Powerby: <a href="https://xx.xxx.vxx/" target="_blank">Me</a>',
                              ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION
                         ]
                     })
                })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            visible:true,
            title: 'Base Layer',
        });
```

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/overview#tile_requests and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/get-api-key

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks you, but I have license API key now, how can I adding GoogleMaps with my key to Openlayers 6.

Comment: See my comment with links to Google docs above.

Comment: I have view through many times but can't find the answer for my question in your links

Comment: From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/overview#tile_requests:  "Partners who are authorized to use this API must have an API key, and the account used to create the API key must be added to the allowlist for access to the Tile API. Authorized partners can contact the Google Maps Support Team for assistance." See also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/overview.  Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, I have buy an API key for myself. I tried with `Simple Map` of Google, API key works fine

Comment: Tried where, in what environment? Please edit your question and add that code.

Comment: I mean I try to add my key to [this google example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/master/dist/samples/map-simple/jsfiddle) to check if the key is working and now I want to add Google Map to base layer of Openlayers

Comment: But this is use in Google maps environment, where API key is enough. Read again what is needed for use of Google tiles elsewhere: "Partners who are authorized to use this API must have an API key, and the account used to create the API key must be added to the allowlist for access to the Tile API. Authorized partners can contact the Google Maps Support Team for assistance." See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/overview

Comment: @TomazicM Thanks you. Sorry for the confusion, I have full permissions for API key

Comment: In that case you can use `ol.source.XYZ` to construct your layer source. Info of how to construct `url` option: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/tile/request-tile. Here is an example of using `ol.source.XYZ` tile source: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz.html

Comment: Unfortunately, `Tile APIs` no longer supports my country so I can't get `session token`. But your suggestion is really valuable to me. Thanks for always helping all my questions, sir ♥.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have access to the tile API you can overlay a Google map with an OpenLayers map (in the same way as the Mapbox map in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html).

There was an example in OpenLayers 3, but only this copy remains http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/21192c7045ab8f50e22e  The maps do not sync well in that now as Google's `setZoom` method animates, so you must use the new `moveCamera` method instead.

Here is the old example updated to the latest OpenLayers https://jsfiddle.net/vharb97t/1/ (edited from the latest tutorials https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials)

Comment: I have full permissions for API key. I will try your examples, thanks a lot.