# OpenLayers with Google Maps JavaScript key

Tags: openlayers, google-maps, google-maps-api

I am using OpenLayers library version 7.2.2 for a client. The client wants Google Maps to be integrated in the system and also has provided with an API key. How can I load the maps using the API key? I was loading Google Maps free version with below mentioned code:

```
source: new XYZ({
        url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@113&hl=en&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
      })
```

How to load all four versions of google maps using above logic?

Comment: Have a look at answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53264869/can-i-integrate-google-map-api-with-openlayers

Comment: For a more recent version which avoids the synchronisation issues see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/443569/102658

Comment: Does this not go against their terms? See: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms 3.2.3 (c) and (e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution provided by Google Customer Support. Just need to add the API key at the end.

```
source: new XYZ({
  url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@113&hl=en&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
})
```